# Elementary question on elementarily equivalence

Tags: logic, model-theory

Source: SHAWN HEDMAN

Definition: Let $M$ and $N$ be $V$-structures. If $M$ and $N$ models the same $V$-sentences, then $M$ and $N$ are said to be elementarily equivalent, denoted $M \equiv N.$

Example: the $V_{<}$-structures $\mathbb{Q}_{<}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{<}$ are elementarily equivalent.

My question: Is not this sentence: $\forall x((x = \pi) \implies$ (x =x))? and the second structure models it? While the first one doesn't as $\pi$ not in $\mathbb{Q}$!

Answer (score 3):

Is $\pi$ even a symbol in $V$? If not this is not a sentence to begin with.

Note that if $\pi$ is in the language then it has to have some interpretation in $\Bbb Q$, but that won't be the same number you think about, but rather some rational number.

Comment: that was cool. Well, how can I prove that they are elementairly equivalent.?

Comment: You can use something like the Tarski-Vaught criterion to show the rationals are an elementary submodel of the reals. Or you can show that the theory of dense ordered sets without endpoints is complete, and therefore every two models are elementarily equivalent.